# Passing Lambda function without std::function with capture [this]

Tags: c++, lambda, arduino

I'm using the 'PacketSerial' library from Github in an Arduino program. In the examples provided with the library, everything is in loop() or setup(). I would like to move all that to the instance 'arDriver', but run into some trouble..

I initialize it like this, which works fine (just like the examples provided);

```cpp
//in app.ino
void setup()
{
  arDriver.setup();  //<- I want to move the 2 functions below in here
  arDriver.myPacketSerial.begin(115200);
  arDriver.myPacketSerial.setPacketHandler([](const uint8_t* buffer, size_t size) 
    {
    arDriver.communicationCOBS(arDriver.myPacketSerial, buffer, size);
    });
}

//in ArduinoDriver.cpp
void ArduinoDriver::communicationCOBS(const PacketSerial& sender, const uint8_t* buffer, size_t size)
{ ... }

//in PacketSerial.h
typedef void (*PacketHandlerFunction)(const uint8_t* buffer, size_t size);
void setPacketHandler(PacketHandlerFunction onPacketFunction)
{ ... }
```

When I move the 2 PacketSerial functions into arDriver::setup(), I get the following;
(after solving an error that I need to capture [this])

```cpp
void ArduinoDriver::setup()
{
  ...
  myPacketSerial.begin(115200);
  myPacketSerial.setPacketHandler([this](const uint8_t* buffer, size_t size)
    {
        communicationCOBS(myPacketSerial, buffer, size);
    });
}
```

Now I get following error which I can't solve;

---

Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "PacketSerial_::setPacketHandler [with EncoderType=COBS, PacketMarker=(uint8_t)'\000', ReceiveBufferSize=256U]" matches the argument list
argument types are: (lambda []void (const uint8_t *buffer, size_t size) -> void)
object type is: PacketSerial

---

I found several posts and questions about similar problems, but lack the skill or knowledge to implement these in my particular application.
Below is what I think is the most promising, but so far, I couldn't make it work..
I prefer not to use a solution based on std::function

```cpp
// from: https://bannalia.blogspot.com/2016/07/passing-capturing-c-lambda-functions-as.html

void do_something(void(*callback)(void*),void* callback_arg)
{
  ...
  callback(callback_arg);
}

int num_callbacks=0;
...
auto callback=[&](){
  std::cout<<"callback called "<<++num_callbacks<<" times \n";
};
auto thunk=[](void* arg){ // note thunk is captureless
  (*static_cast<decltype(callback)*>(arg))();
};
do_something(thunk,&callback);

output: callback called 1 times
```

Comment: You make a template function if you want to pass a lambda. Captureless lambdas aren't convertible to functions - at least thus far, IIRC C++20 supports this feature.

Comment: @ALX23z captureless lambdas are convertible to function pointers

Comment: When you say " I couldn't make it work" what does that mean? Didn't compile? Crashed? Soemthing else?

Comment: Are you in control of the packet-serial's interface, i. e. can you modify it?

Comment: The 'most promising' approach requires an *additional* `void*` parameter for the callback function; if you had such, you could simply pass `this` as exactly this additional argument...

Comment: That library (is bad and) assumes you only ever have one `PacketSerial` at a time. If you have more, you are out of luck. Otherwise you can (ab)use a global `ArduinoDriver *` and a free function